# tk window got smaller when added a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I type a simple hello world gui with a button that does nothing, the tk window doesn't do what I wanted. I want the window to remain 500 x 500 while there's a small button in the top left. Here's my current simple code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.config(height = 500, width = 500) #the window initialize as a 500px x 500px window
button = Button(window, text = 'hello world')  
button.pack() #but when I added a button, the window shinks to the size of the button
window.mainloop()
```

I'm running Mac Sierra with python 3.6. And downloadeded an external tkl as told by the manual.

[Srcreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDl2W.png)

Answer (score 1):

Heyo, the expand function will fill the remaining areas with empty space. You can set expand to any value as long as it's not 0, and it will do so.

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.config(height = 500, width = 500)
button = Button(window, text = 'hello world')  
button.pack(expand = 1) #Lookie here
window.mainloop()
```

Good luck to whatever project you're working on. :D